# Session TimeOut without doing any activity

Tags: java

I am trying to understand that, In web.xml file and inside api folder written code for session timeout but I am bit confused which code is working for session timeout.

inside is web.xml:
        480

inside api folder code is:

```
public HttpClient() {
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", HTTP_PORT,
                                      PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", HTTPS_PORT, 
                                        SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));

    PoolingClientConnectionManager connectionManager = 
                            new PoolingClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry);
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(200);
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50);
    HttpHost localhost = new HttpHost("locahost", HTTP_PORT);
    connectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(localhost), 50);
    this.defaultHttpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) 
                  HttpClientWrapper.wrapClient(new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager));

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 1200000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 1200000);
    this.defaultHttpClient.setParams(httpParameters);

    this.httpContext = new SyncBasicHttpContext();
}
```

Comment: `web.xml` is a server-side file and the timeout is controlled by the server

Comment: But the timeout happens around after 2 hrs.In web.xml it's                    
    <session-config>
     <session-timeout>480</session-timeout>
 </session-config>